# Is there a lexer generator that can take standard lex files and produce a lexer in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, lex, lexer

I'm playing with CodeMirror, a browser-based editor written in JavaScript. It has a pluggable syntax highlighting component. I'd like to be able to take standard lex files for an arbitrary language and generate a lexer in JavaScript that I could plug into CodeMirror. Is there such a lexer generator available?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lexer written in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823612/lexer-written-in-javascript)

Comment: @Bergi : I saw that, but I need something that would accept a lex file as input.