# Implementing a tag search with operands

Tags: sql, search, web, tags, operators

I've been trying to implement a tag based search where users may type a string of tags using the operators & | and ! along with the ability to group search terms [i.e. (X&Y)|!Z]. My plan is to then be able to translate there short string into a full SQL query that may search for objects which have been linked with particular tags.

```
object    >--<    tags
object -< bond >- tags

 -----------    -----------------------    ------
| object    |  | bond                  |  | tag  |
 -----------    ---- -------- ---------    ------ 
| Id | Name |  | Id | textId | tagName |  | Name |
 ---- ------    ---- -------- ---------    ------ 
| 1  | A    |  | 1  | 1      | V       |  | V    |
| 2  | B    |  | 2  | 1      | W       |  | W    |
| 3  | C    |  | 3  | 1      | X       |  | X    |
 ---- ------   | 4  | 2      | Z       |  | Y    |
               | 5  | 3      | V       |  | Z    |
               | 6  | 3      | W       |   ------
               | 7  | 3      | X       |
               | 8  | 3      | Y       |
                ---- -------- ---------

SEARCH: 
    (X&Y)|Z

QUERY:{
    SELECT *
    FROM object
    WHERE object.id = bond.textId
    AND (
        (bond.tagName = 'X' AND bond.tagName = 'Y')
        OR bond.tagName = 'Z'
    )

RETURN: 
    2 | B
    3 | C
```

I have written the following to compile the query
http://jsfiddle.net/wP7JR/1/

and the following to test my query
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/139ca/3/0

However, I notice a few problems and am looking for guidance:

- First and foremost, I have been searching and searching for resources which discuss this problem, solutions to this problem and so on. However, my biggest problem is I do not know what the best search is... I'm sure there's a name for this type of problem, there always is.
- Secondly, My SQL is clearly amateur and wrong since a search for tagName <> 'Y' I would want to return objects 1 and 2 but instead I receive 1, 2 and 3 since there are bonds where object 3 is not linked to Y.
- My search for (tagName = 'X' & tagName = 'Y') returns nothing and I know the reason for this is that there are no occurances of objects where tag X and Y are linked at the same time...

So, hence forth, I'm looking for a bit of guidance to resolving my problem.

Thinks to search for, similar problems, solutions(?), alternative solutions(? If my one is not an optimal way of solving this problem).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you could accomplish a solution to your problem implementing a [Binary Expression Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_expression_tree), and then given that structure you could start creating your SQL begining from the most-left node (in fact, you have to use inorder, post-order or pre-order according to your expression format).

Other solution, a little bit more complex, could be working with lexers and parsers, generating your own grammar.. [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823612/lexer-written-in-javascript)

As your other questions, you'll first have to define what operator '&' would do.. tagname = 'X' & tagname = 'Y' means that item have at least these two tags and not that item could have X or Y tag.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. I have found this article which should help me with my implementation: www.codeproject.com/Articles/198236/Boolean-text-search-queries-and-their-processing

It looks like quite a mammoth task, and in the meantime I have been working on my SQL statements which are also becoming quite mammoth...

Comment: However, I have also found this: http://tagging.pui.ch/post/37027745720/tags-database-schemas Which appears to offer far simpler ways of achieving what I am aiming to achieve which isn't actually going to be far off the same way posts of a blog are retrieved via tags. I think I'll attempt this version as I am keen on just getting something implemented :) Thanks for helping me find the answer!